# Qt graphical button

Tags: qt

I'd like to create a button in Qt that is the size and shape of a PNG that I give it. I've tried using a QToolButton with setAutoRaise set to true so that the 3D frame only appears on mouseover and press, but I don't want that 3D frame to extend beyond the PNG. Setting the icon size and/or the button's min and max sizes isn't helping.

In other words, I'd like the functionality of buttons like on (say) iOS, instead of something that one would expect on a Windows dialog box. The chrome that QToolButton provides (the 3D frame) is great and I still want that sort of behavior, but it seems like I'd have to do everything by hand -- ie, draw the mouseover, depressed, and disabled versions of the button.

Is there some way to treat a QToolButton's icon as the entire extents of the button? Or is there another control that I could use instead?

Comment: Depending on the style of button you need to create, you may be able to get the look you need using Qt's Style sheets to style the button (e.g. rounded edges, different colors, fonts, etc.). This will give you the ability to style all of your buttons without having to subclass and code everything. It depends on the look you're going for, though. Take a look at the [Qt style sheet information](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) and see if stylesheets will suit your needs.

Comment: My designers are also working on mobile platforms and want to just give me a PNG, and not deal with platform-specific chrome. I've looked at style sheets and they provide a lot, but what I'm trying to do is get rid of *all* the chrome.